# how to read value from URL? asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

its a full url:

```
http://localhost:64075/WPMManagement/Image/id=09251a7f-c362-4ed9-98e2-c9d555aaaf4f
```

it my asp.net mvc view:

```
<img height="660px" 
     width="430px" 
     src="<%= Url.Action("WebPageImage", "WPMManagement", new { id = id }) %>"
     alt="bild mit webseiten version" />
```

how can I read id from URL which above, and insert it instead `id = "id"` - > `id = "09251a7f-c362-4ed9-98e2-c9d555aaaf4f`" ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `id` is part of your route data:

```
<img 
    height="660px" 
    width="430px" 
    src="<%= Url.Action("WebPageImage", "WPMManagement", new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] }) %>" 
    alt="bild mit webseiten version" 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, from what I can see that URL does not contain any querystrings:

```
http://localhost:64075/WPMManagement/Image/id=09251a7f-c362-4ed9-98e2-c9d555aaaf4f
```

If you'd have a `?id=` you'd be able to write `Request["id"]` in your view, but in the case of the abovementioned URL this will return `null`.
In other words, the correct url in order to use `Request["id"]` is:

```
http://localhost:64075/WPMManagement/Image/?id=09251a7f-c362-4ed9-98e2-c9d555aaaf4f
```

However, if you're Route indicates that the part after /Image/ is the Id, you can remove the id= all together, and the resulting URL would be:

```
http://localhost:64075/WPMManagement/Image/09251a7f-c362-4ed9-98e2-c9d555aaaf4f
```

This should enable you to get the Id of the current RouteValues dictionary

Answer (score 0):

`Request.QueryString["id"]` will help :o)

Comment: should i write it in view inside id? like id=<% Request.QueryString["id"]%>?

Comment: Write it in your method behind. If you are using MVC3, then you can use the `ViewBag` like so: `ViewBag.Id = Request.QueryString["id"];`.  But, it seems that adding it straight in seems to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img height="660px" width="430px" src="<%= Url.Action("WebPageImage", "WPMManagement", new { id = Request.QueryString["id"] }) %>"
        alt="bild mit webseiten version" />
```